# Installing elementary OS as third dist for testing

Tags: system-installation, grub

First post here so HI THERE!

I'm really interested in eOS, especially after the liveusb test and want to install it now for long term testing.
I bother about my other installed distros because I experienced problems with installing further distros on another laptop.

My main Distro is Linux mint 19.2 Cinnamon so far and I got Win7 installed as well. First choice in the grub menue is Lmint. Is there a safe way to install eOS as a third distro without harming my actual system? I have to admit that I'm still a very low experienced user so if something goes wrong it would mean bigger trouble to me automatically.

Would you risk it?

Thanks in advance!
Jo

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it easily !
First of all, you need to create new partitions for eOS Distro (including his own swap if you have one for Mint (if both use the same swap, it's could have effect if you hibernate one and you boot the other one).

When you install eOS, or every linux distribution, by default an installation of grub is part of the linux distro installation. And grub can detect you windows, your mint and your eOS.
If you don't want to risk anything, do not install grub when you install eOS. After that, boot on your mint distribution. Then update your grub list using `sudo update-grub` and the new eOS will appear.

The best way to install multiple distro without risking anything between them is to use UEFI Bios and GPT partitions. If you do that, you can boot directly from the UEFI bios into your prefered partition which contains OS. But for that, you need to setup your bios as an UEFI bios and all your installation must be in GPT mode (and not MBR). If your current installation is not UEFI, this is a lot of work and risks. But for my PC, I have this installation and I can boot from UEFI bios even I destroy an OS boot, an SSD or whatever.

Advantage : 
Boot faster because your boot a partition, not the GRUB Loader. (I boot directly into windows, I press F8 while my BIOS is booting to get more choices (Hackintosh/Windows 10 for me), I press F2 to setup default configuration into my UEFI bios directly.
No dependency between your loader (because there is no loader like GRUB) and your multiple OS installation. Your OS depends directly from your UEFI Bios.
You can add and remove partitions easily with no risks (don't delete the wrong partition, that's all).

If you have more question, you can ask me (my english is poor, sorry for that).

Comment: Hi Shining,thanks A LOT(!) for your detailed answer. Unfortunately it seemed to risky for me installing eOS on my main hdd, espacially with your BIOS Advices, i didn't get completely. So I ordered a cheap 250gb ssd instead, removed my mail hdd and installed eOS on that. Until now I'm quite flashed about it and am looking forward to working with it. I will keep my former hdd for case of any biggger problems so i can change back on a running system. Until now I wont expect that to happen, though :D. Thanks again and best regards, Jo

Comment: No problem. If you want more informations or advices, just ask me.